# PHP Array to string conversion in insert

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to use new PDO class, and once i tried to use the function insert  I got a notice and I am lost .

The Notice :

> **Notice**: Array to string conversion in

The line :

```
    $id = $db->insert('users', array("name" => "namei"));
```

The class is :
https://github.com/tommyknocker/pdo-database-class

If anyone have better pdo class I glad.

Comment: what framework is this?

Comment: And which PDO class would that be?

Comment: @dnFer edited thanks

Comment: Would be useful to have a full stack trace of this notice, to see where it flops

Comment: @Jarek.D the notice in this line on this array I wroted